# how to find result grid in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I can't find the result grid in Mysql workbench only output tab is coming
here is a screenshot . I ran the query still nothing came but the output tab shows that the rows has been returned

[image: result grid not coming screenshot]

please help i am new to this

Comment: Did you look at the dropdown list where it now shows *Action Output*? What other choices are in that list?

Comment: it has 3 choices Action Output Text Output History Output

Comment: The [documentation for MySQL Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-develop.html) should help you get going.

Comment: its too long i dont have enough time to go through all that ... i have seen the result grid part but its not helping

Comment: Sorry. We're too busy helping people to hold your hand. Seriously, read the documentation - I went through it and narrowed the location down for you to save you time. If you don't have time to read it yourself, you probably don't have the time to be using Workbench.

Comment: Google for: workbench SQL View panel not visible

Comment: its working now .... @KenWhite thanks

Comment: @MainakDeb what was the problem? Once you run a query which returns results you should also see the result grid. Never heard of problems with that on Windows.

Comment: Yes sir ... The problem was coming ... When I installed the mySQL the problem was there ... Then it's working fine when today I put up the connection

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and restart of the program helped me on Mysql workbench 8.0.11 CE

Answer (score 1):

In  Workbanch 8.0.11 ce win7 same issue. Restart Workbanch and run select help.